# handle sending sms between users over Twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms, twilio

I've read [THIS](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio) Twilio post on how to enable text messaging between users. I am building using Ruby on Rails.

At the moment, this is what I have:

- A messaging system in my app where users can inbox each other.
- When a user X messages another user Y, the application also sends that message to user Y's email address. User Y can reply to the message on the app or by responding to the email received by user X. If user Y choses to respond to the email (inbound email) my application processes the email received - it knows that it is intended for user X so it will forward that the email to user X's email address.

This is great because I'm giving the user several means of communication between each other (in app or email).

Now i'd like a similar but instead using the [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) API.

Particularly i'd like to enable this type of communication:
As per [Twilio help center](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio)

I'm having trouble understanding the concept of having multiple numbers that can be used by different user but somehow you know who's the message for...( Wow, I'm even having trouble describing what i'm having trouble with!)

I'm using the [Ruby wrapper for the Twilio API](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby)

To send a message to user it is fairly simple:

```
# set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

# send sms
@client.messages.create(
  from: 'twilio_number',
  to: 'a user number',
  body: 'Hey there!'
)
```

To receive a message:

First configure the your Twilio phone number request url to point to an endpoint in your application. In my case its 'yourappurl.com/twilio/create'.

```
class TwilioController < ApplicationController

  include Webhookable

  after_filter :set_header
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    # inbound messages arrive here. Need to do something with the message, identify who's it for
    # the receiving user and where its coming from ( the user who sent the text message)
    render_twiml response
  end

end
```

However this is for my application sending a message to a user's phone number. How can I handle communication between two users where user X can communicate with user Y via text messages (all going through my application)

Comment: I'd like some explanation about the downvote received. I am willing to improve my question and provide additional code if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The help centre article on [sending messages between users](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/how-can-i-have-users-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-twilio) has a great explanation of how to implement this in theory, however you probably want to see some code.

Your best bet is to work through this tutorial on [Masked numbers with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/ruby/rails) which shows you practically how you would purchase a number for a user and then connect two users through that number.

In brief, you need to get a number that represents a relationship between two users. When you receive a message at that number and you get the webhook from Twilio then you can look up the relationship based on the Twilio number the message was sent to and the number it was sent from. You can then connect and send the message on to the number on the other side of the relationship.

But, as I said, I recommend going through the [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/ruby/rails) to really learn this in depth.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'll take a look at the tutorial and read the documentation. Will get back to you soon. Thanks !!!

Comment: Do let me know if there's anything more I can do to help. Cheers!

Comment: Looks like Copilot is what fits best my situation. Do you agree?

Comment: Copilot is good for sending lots of messages from a pool of numbers, but it doesn't handle incoming and outgoing messages the way you need. You'll still need to build the logic to connect two users yourself, I'm afraid.

Comment: I see. I do not need to worry about buying numbers on the fly though right ?
Also, is there an specific id that I can use to determine who's sending the message and who is it for?

Comment: The logic in my application side would be fairly simple if I can easily determine the destination and provenance of the message.

Comment: You don't need to buy numbers on the fly, but you would want to maintain a pool of numbers as big as the maximum number of relationships a user can have. In terms of determining who sent the message and who it's for, you need to create a relationship that ties together 3 numbers, each user's number and the Twilio number that connects them. Then, when one user sends a message to your Twilio number, you can look up the relationship and forward that message on to the other number in the relationship. Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense thanks! Would that mean one twilio number for every pair of users? That's a lot of numbers...

Comment: Nope, like I said, you only need as many numbers as the maximum  number of relationships a user can have, the help centre article I linked in the original answer has a good explanation of how that would work.

Comment: Just FYI the [sample app](http://airtng-wa.herokuapp.com/) on the [Workflow Automation tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/workflow-automation/ruby/rails#14) is failing. Other than that the tutorials are great and have shed some light on my issue. Last thing, do I need to integrate Authy for phone verification ? I've already set up phone verification in my app but i'm not sure it's using Authy. I'm wondering whats the best way to implement  phone verification as an optional way to get users account verified.

Comment: Thanks for reporting the tutorial demo isn't working! Could you drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com, we'd love to send you something! In terms of phone verification, if you've already implemented it yourself, then you're probably fine. If you were starting on that feature now, I'd probably recommend Authy as it handles a bunch of stuff for you.